# Typescript : Search if an array (row) exists in a 2D array

Tags: typescript, search, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to check if an array of coordinates [x,y,z] exists in a 2D array of other coordinates [[x,y,z],[x',y',z'],..]. I wonder if `indexOf` can be used here.

```
var ALLcoordinates:number[][];
ALLcoordinates = [];

var coordinates: number[];
coordinates = [alea1, alea2, alea3];


for (var i=0; i< dims; i++) {
    ALLcoordinates[i]=[];
    for (var j=0; j<chainSize; j++){
        ALLcoordinates[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

So how can I make Typescript search "by rows"? Can I adapt `indexOf` for 2D arrays, or I do have to use loops? Here is my code, but I get quite an obvious error on data type : *"Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'."*

```
if (coordinates.indexOf(ALLcoordinates) == -1) {

        // do stuff
 }
```

I would be glad for any help or ideas, thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a `function` for it:

```
let ALLcoordinates:number[][] = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];
let coordinates1: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
let coordinates2: number[] = [2, 3, 1];

function contains(array2d: number[][], array: number[]) {
    let result = array2d.filter((item) => {
        if(item.length === array.length) {
            for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                if(item[i] !== array[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    return result.length > 0;
}

console.log(contains(ALLcoordinates, coordinates1)); //true
console.log(contains(ALLcoordinates, coordinates2)); //false
```

Testable [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20ALLcoordinates%3Anumber%5B%5D%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%5B4%2C%205%2C%206%5D%2C%5B7%2C%208%2C%209%5D%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20coordinates1%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20coordinates2%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B2%2C%203%2C%201%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20contains(array2d%3A%20number%5B%5D%5B%5D%2C%20array%3A%20number%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20array2d.filter((item)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(item.length%20%3D%3D%3D%20array.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20item.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(item%5Bi%5D%20!%3D%3D%20array%5Bi%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20result.length%20%3E%200%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(contains(ALLcoordinates%2C%20coordinates1))%3B%20%2F%2Ftrue%0D%0Aconsole.log(contains(ALLcoordinates%2C%20coordinates2))%3B%20%2F%2Ffalse) (check console for output)

Answer (score 0):

I would declare two custom classes `Vector3` & `Pair`:

```
class Vector3 {

    public constructor(
        public x: number,
        public y: number,
        public z: number
    ) { }

    public isEqual(vector: Vector3) {
        return vector.x === this.x &&
            vector.x === this.x &&
            vector.x === this.x; 
    }

}

class Pair {

    public constructor(
        private v1: Vector3,
        private v2: Vector3
    ) { }

    public getIndex(vector: Vector3) {
        if (this.v1.isEqual(vector)) return 0;
        if (this.v2.isEqual(vector)) return 1;
        return -1;
    }

    public contains(vector: Vector3) {
        return this.getIndex(vector) !== -1;
    }

}
```

Then you will end up with a nice API for your use case:

```
const v1 = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
const v2 = new Vector3(4, 5, 6);
const v3 = new Vector3(7, 8, 9);

const pair = new Pair(v1, v2);

console.log(
    pair.contains(v1), // true
    pair.contains(v2), // true
    pair.contains(v3)  // false
);
```

Comment: That looks great, but a bit too "heavy" for my project. If indexOf can not be applied, then I'll just use a function.. Thanks :)